# Main UserForm for Search-Function - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using my module to access individual UserForms that all have the same structure. It would be nice to have a central UserForm, but unfortunately I have no idea how to merge the codes so that only the respective TextBox or CommandButtons are displayed and executed.

Here are the codes I used for the individual UserForms:

UserForm 1:

```
Option Explicit

Public Search term As String

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Search term = TextBox2.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Search2_Initialize()
    TextBox2.Text = Search term ' Set the previous search term in the TextBox
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Search term = TextBox2.Text ' Save the current search term
    SearchAndMarkUIDPurification Search term
    Unload Me 
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    SearchAndMarkUIDPurification "" 
    Search term = "" 
    Unload Me 
End Sub
```

UserForm 2:

```
Option Explicit

Public Search term As String

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    Search term = TextBox3.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Search3_Initialize()
    TextBox3.Text = Search term 
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    ' Button to start the search
    Search term = TextBox3.Text 
    SearchAndMarkUIDAdd1 Search term
    Unload Me 
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

    SearchAndMarkUIDAdd1 "" 
    Search term = "" 
    Unload Me 
End Sub
```

Best regards and thanks in advance, Jamie

Comment: Why are you using `Unload Me` over `Me.Hide`? You wouldn't need `Search term` (which is hopefully a typo since you can't have a variable out of two words (separated by a spacebar)). You could technically still use it for button 4/6 but you could also just clear textboxes 2/3.